# determine if selectize input has focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I can usually determine if a particular input has focus using `$("#my_input").is(":focus")` but this doesn't seem to work for selectize inputs.

I can set the focus for the input using `$("#my_input")[0].selectize.focus()` but then still `$("#my_input").is(":focus")` returns `false`.

When I inspect the element in Chrome I can see that a div right below `my_input` has the class attribute `focus` but it is not clear to me how to link this to `#my_input`.

I have also tried `document.activeElement` and `document.activeElement.parentElement`, etc. but no luck so far

Comment: The selectize has a prop called isFocused, I'm using it to check if the selectize is focused. Example: $('#yourSelector')[0].selectize.isFocused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Selectize.js](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) is hiding the input you wrote in your markup and shows some dynamic elements instead.

Those are next to your original input.

Try:

```
if( $("#my_input").next(".selectize-control").find(".focus").length>0 ){
  console.log("Selectize is focussed!");
}else{
  console.log("Selectize is NOT focussed.");
}
```

If you follow me on this... By looking in the "next" div if there is a child having the `focus` class, you'll know if it's focussed or not..

Comment: Related issue was getting the value of the element. `$('#yourSelector').selectize()[0].selectize.getValue()`, as suggested by @zmirc, worked

Comment: The selectize has a prop called isFocused, I'm using it to check if the selectize is focused.
   
  
Example: ```$('#yourSelector')[0].selectize.isFocused```